# Using AccessToken stored in string variable in a new Graph Request

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am a novice programmer trying to use graph API to post a photo to a Facebook page.But I need the page access token for that.I stored the page accesssToken into a string variable using this..

```
  AccessToken token=AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                token,
                "/me/accounts",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        // Insert your code here
                        try {

                            JSONObject res=new JSONObject(response.toString());

                            JSONArray data=res.getJSONArray("data");

                             accessToken = "";

                            for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++){

                                JSONObject temp=data.getJSONObject(i);

                                if(temp.has("access_token")){

                                    accessToken=temp.getString("access_token");

                                    break;

                                }

                            }

                        }catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        request.executeAsync();
```

Now I need to use this accessToken in another graph Request for posting the photos into the Facebook page.But since I have the token in string format I am not able to use it in the new Graph Request.

Can you guys help me with **converting the string Token to an AccessToken Object**.I have seen the Documentation but could not get an I idea on what to be done...so Please Help me..Thanks